# GoodData: What are the rate limits on the API?

Tags: api, gooddata

Are there any rate limits on the GoodData API? Like number of requests per minute/second/hour/...?

Comment: That seems like a question entirely for whoever it is that creates that API?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be directed at their support.

Comment: Questions for whoever makes the API or has been rate limited before. I didn't find it in the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default GoodData limits API call volume to 5000 calls per minute. A 429 HTTP code is returned if the the limit is exceeded. It is a rolling window, so you can retry after a short period of time (at most one minute).

This limit can be increased per GoodData customer however it depends on your use case. If you possibly need the limit raised you will need to work with GoodData Support.